# Python - How to add zeros to and integer/string?

Tags: python

I'm without clues on how to do this in Python. The problem is the following: I have for example an orders numbers like:

```
1
2
...
234567
```

I need to extract only the 4 last digits of the order number and if the order number have less than 4 digits I will substitute with zeros.

The required output is like this:

```
0001
0002
...
4567
```

Any clues? I'm a bit lost with this one.

Best Regards,

Comment: The question is not an exact duplicate, as it looks for padding AND cutting to fix size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> n = 234567
>>> ("%04d"%n)[-4:]
'4567'
```

Explanation ([docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)):

```
"%04d"%n --> get a string from the (d)ecimal n, putting leading 0s to reach 4 digits (if needed)
```

but this operation preserves all the digits:

```
>>> n = 7
>>> "%04d"%n
'0007'   
>>> n = 234567
>>> "%04d"%n
'234567'
```

So, if you want last 4 digits, just take the characters from position -4 (i.e. 4 chars from the right, see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) when dealing with 'slice notation'):

```
>>> n = 234567
>>> ("%04d"%n)[-4:]
'4567'
```

Comment: Great! It works. What does exactly the "%04d"?. Can you explain the magic? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following:

```
>>> test = [1, 234567]
>>> for num in test:
        last4 = str(num)[-4:]
        print last4.zfill(4)

0001
4567
```